# Maven provided dependencies

Tags: spring, maven

I am working on an app that is using the following maven dependency (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-spring/1.3.0)

It says below the dependency that spring-jdbc is a 'provided dependency'

However, I don't see it in the 'Maven Dependencies' folder and my app won't run unless I manually add spring-jdbc to the dependencies. Why isn't maven doing this for me?

Comment: A provided dependency means it will be provided by the environment you run on which means in your case you need to add those dependencies you need.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that Maven grabbed the dependencies of dependencies, so I didn't need to hunt for them myslef

Comment: Yes of course but if someone has decided to set scope provided it is more flexible. So you can now decide which exact version you would like to use. In relationship with libraries this is often the case.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean I should be confirming a dependencies provided dependencies are in the project every time I add a dependency? I'm new to Maven so I'm just trying to figure out how to best avoid errors caused by missing dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line type for:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

in order to pull/grab dependencies from a remote repository to your local repository, that's including the transitive dependencies. (which means, dependencies of dependency you're trying to pull).